# Session variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I have a asp.net webapplicatoin using session variables. I clear the session values when session_end is fired but the when the application is opened in a new window after closing the previous window, the session values retain.

is there a way that we can get rid of session values.

Thanks in advance ...
Phani

Comment: I'd recommend clearing out the session values as soon as you're done with them, rather than waiting for session_end (which may or may not fire).

Comment: The session_start is 'guaranteed' to fire, but unfortunately the session_end is not, so don't rely on that. Can you use a logout event?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, Brian and Michel. Unfortunately I dont have an option to logout and I cannot clear session values as they being used all over the application. Any other suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

New **windows/tabs** don't create new sessions, new **browser instances** do.

Also, when the session ends, the session variables are gone. You just can't control when the GC deletes them from memory, however they are no longer accessible.

Answer (score 0):

A session does not end when simply closing a window. The session ends when it expires. ASP.NET has no way of knowing if a user closes the window. See [MSDN on SessionStateModule.End Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413407/asp-net-session-timeout/1413426#1413426) for a more thorough explanation.

Of the top of my head, what you could do is detect when the user closes the window e.g. using the unload() event in jQuery, and send a request to a webservice that then ends the session.