# Do some functionality on session timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

How can i write some code like maintaining timeout in database or logging task, when session get timeout automatically after specific time(default 20 mins).

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621744/how-to-handle-session-end-in-global-asax

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413407/asp-net-session-timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Session_OnEnd Event`, you can find all the related `methods` and `properties` about [Session Object (IIS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Please have a look [Session-State Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx)

Also there is good article about [ASP.NET Session End Event Fires Immediately After Session Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246649/ASP-NET-Session_End-event-fires-immediately-after)